# case_when NA/NaN when using variables to generate a range based condition

Tags: r, dplyr, case

I'm trying to generate sequence based on a mod result being in a range defined by variables which are integers,

All the methods I've tried so far fail  with this sort of error message:

> Caused by error in `case_when()`:
> ! Failed to evaluate the left-hand side of formula 1.
> Caused by error in `a:b`:    ! NA/NaN argument

Where the variables are contiguous this approach  works,
albeit with a warning unless I use `dplyr::rowwise`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(cond = rep(c("a1", NA, "a1", NA), each = 20),
                  a = 1,
                  b = 3,
                  year = rep(1:20, 4),
                  freq = 5)

df1_new <-
  df1 |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(new_var = case_when(cond == "a1" & year %% 5 %in% a:b ~ 1,
                             TRUE ~ 0))
```

The result should look like this:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(df1_new, aes(year, new_var)) +
  ggplot2::geom_col()
```

But my data is much more complex in reality, in this case
curiously this dataframe does produce the data required without
`rowwise` but with `rowwise` it fails with the error message above.

```
df2 <- data.frame(cond = rep(c("a1", NA, "a1", NA), each = 20),
                  a = rep(c(1, NA_real_), each = 20),
                  b = rep(c(3, NA_real_), each = 20),
                  year = rep(1:20, 4),
                  freq = 5)


df2_new <-
   df2 |>
 rowwise() |>
  mutate(new_var = case_when(cond == "a1" & year %% 5 %in% a:b ~ 1,
                            TRUE ~ 0))
```

Any help with identifying the problem and pointers to better coding approach would be really appreciated. And help understand what is going on here.

Comment: You can't make a sequence of numbers including an `NA` or `NaN` - e.g. `NA:2` or `seq(NA,2)` is an error. Maybe you could reframe as `year >= a & year <= b` which would at least avoid getting an error before the calculation? (Though it would still return `NA`)

Comment: So if I understand this correctly case_when steps through the rows of data assessing all conditions for each case.  I somehow thought that in the example where there first condition failed case_when would not continue to the next condition. I tried using && rather than & but this did not help in my real world case.

Comment: Nope - `case_when` calculates all conditions and does not step through each one.

Comment: Thinking about this it has to be the case (no pun intended) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
df1 |>
  mutate(new_var = !is.na(cond) & cond == "a1" & between(year %% 5, a, b))

# or, if you have more conditions you haven't shared with us:
df1 |>
  mutate(new_var = case_when(
    !is.na(cond) & cond == "a1" & between(year %% 5, a, b) ~ TRUE,
    TRUE ~ FALSE
  ))
```

There's a few issues:

1. comparing things to NA will always be NA. If you don't want NAs, you need to include an `!is.na(x)` check, where x is the thing you don't want to be NA. It has to be first, otherwise it will hit one of the other logic conditions and will evaluate to NA instead
2. (as shown in the code) you don't need case_when when you have only one condition- `ifelse`, `if_else`, or simply the condition itself is fine
3. thelatemail's comment about NAs in number sequences

Comment: This is helpful thankyou; I should have been more explicit: there are multiple cases. the MRE tries to reproduce the case which causes failure.

Comment: The `between(year %% 5, a, b)` is the saving function. In my real case example I have to check 5 variables for `na` before running the mod condition. I don't suppose there is an elegant way of doing that apart from stringing together all the `!is.na(...) & !is.na(...) ...`?

Comment: you can use map_lgl :-)